# The document has been closed. You can't add any Elements

Tags: spring, itextpdf

I am using the below code:

```
protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
    Document document, PdfWriter writer,
    HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        ArrayList<OrderDetails> list = (ArrayList<OrderDetails>)model.get("orderDetailsList");
        document.setMargins(-24, -24, 135,60);        
        writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788));
        HeaderFooter event = new HeaderFooter();
        writer.setPageEvent((PdfPageEvent) event);
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfPTable upperTable = new PdfPTable(3);
        upperTable.setTotalWidth(515);
        upperTable.getDefaultCell().setPadding(6);
        upperTable.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);

        for(OrderDetails orderDetails : list) {
            document.open();  
            Font f3 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12.0f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.GREEN);
            Font f1 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12.0f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
            Font f2 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12.0f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
            PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(4);
            Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA);
            font.setColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
            // define table header cell
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
            cell2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
            cell2.setPadding(5);
            cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            table1.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            // write table header
            cell2.setPhrase(new Phrase("Sno", font));
            table1.addCell(cell2);
            cell2.setPhrase(new Phrase("ISBN", font));
            table1.addCell(cell2);
            cell2.setPhrase(new Phrase("Quantity", font));
            table1.addCell(cell2);
            cell2.setPhrase(new Phrase("Status", font));
            table1.addCell(cell2);
            Date strDate=orderDetails.getDataInserted();
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            String createdDate = formatter.format(strDate);
            upperTable.setWidths(new float[] {33,33,33});
            upperTable.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            upperTable.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.BLACK);      
            upperTable.addCell(new Phrase("  Bhavish Order Id :"+orderDetails.getBhavishOrderId(),f1));
            upperTable.addCell(new Phrase("Client Name:"+orderDetails.getClientName(),f1));
            upperTable.addCell(new Phrase("    Order Date:"+orderDetails.getOrderDate(),f1));   
            upperTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1,40,734,cb );
            upperTable.flushContent();  
            upperTable = new PdfPTable(2); 
            upperTable.setTotalWidth(515);
            upperTable.getDefaultCell().setPadding(6);       
            upperTable.setWidths(new float[] {70,30});
            PdfPCell cell1 = upperTable.getDefaultCell();
            cell1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
            code128.setBarHeight(10);
            code128.setSize(5);
            code128.setCode("0123456789");
            upperTable.addCell(new Phrase("Batch ID :"+orderDetails.getBatchId(),f2));
            upperTable.getDefaultCell().setRowspan(2);
            upperTable.addCell(code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null));
            upperTable.getDefaultCell().setRowspan(1);
            upperTable.addCell(new Phrase("Epz/Nepz  :"+orderDetails.getEpzNepz(),f2));
            document.add(upperTable);
            upperTable.flushContent();   
            upperTable = new PdfPTable(3);
            upperTable.setWidths(new float[] {40,30,30});
            upperTable.setTotalWidth(515);
            upperTable.getDefaultCell().setPadding(6);        
            upperTable.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);         
            upperTable.addCell(new Phrase("        Order Details -  :",f1)); 
            upperTable.addCell(new Phrase("Type:"+orderDetails.getOrderType(),f1)); 
            upperTable.addCell(new Phrase("  On :"+createdDate,f1));  
            document.add(upperTable);
            upperTable.flushContent();   
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);   
            table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            table.setWidths(new float[] {19,2,29,20,2,29});     
            table.setSpacingBefore(5);
            table.getDefaultCell().setPadding(6);
            PdfPCell cell = table.getDefaultCell();
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            table.addCell(new Phrase("Client Name :",f2));       
            table.addCell(new Phrase(":"));      
            table.addCell(new Phrase(orderDetails.getClientName()));
            table.addCell(new Phrase("Urgent/Normal :",f2));         
            table.addCell(new Phrase(":"));       
            table.addCell(new Phrase(orderDetails.getNormalUrgent()));    
            table.addCell(new Phrase("Order Number :",f2));       
            table.addCell(new Phrase(":"));      
            table.addCell(new Phrase(orderDetails.getOrderNumber()));
            Set<OrderIsbnDetails> list1  = orderDetails.getOrderIsbnDetails(); 
            int ListISBN=list1.size();
            table.addCell(new Phrase("Total ISBN :",f2));         
            table.addCell(new Phrase(":"));       
            table.addCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(ListISBN)));    
            document.add(table);
            table.flushContent();   
            int i=0;
            for (OrderIsbnDetails orderIsbnDetails : list1) {   
                i=i+1;
                table1.setWidthPercentage(70.0f);
                table1.setWidths(new float[] {0.2f, 1.0f, 0.4f, 1.0f});
                table1.setSpacingBefore(0);
                cell2.setPhrase(new Phrase(String.valueOf(i),font));
                cell2.setVerticalAlignment (Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table1.addCell(cell2);
                cell2.setPhrase(new Phrase(orderIsbnDetails.getIsbn(),font));
                System.out.println("The ISBN List "+orderIsbnDetails.getIsbn());
                cell2.setVerticalAlignment (Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table1.addCell(cell2);
                cell2.setPhrase(new Phrase(String.valueOf(orderIsbnDetails.getQuantity()),font));
                System.out.println("The ISBN List "+String.valueOf(orderIsbnDetails.getQuantity()));
                cell2.setVerticalAlignment (Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table1.addCell(cell2);
                cell2.setPhrase(new Phrase(orderIsbnDetails.getIsbnstatus(),font));
                System.out.println("The ISBN Status"+orderIsbnDetails.getIsbnstatus());
                cell2.setVerticalAlignment (Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table1.addCell(cell2);
                document.add(table1);
                table1.flushContent();
            }
            document.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("To Check the error In Order Detail PDF"+e);
    }
}
```

It throws the following error:

> The document has been closed. 
>   You can't add any Elements.

Comment: i am using ItextPdf ...Where i Want to close the document

Answer (score 2):

Please format your code properly, and you'll see that you are violating the "create a document in 5 steps" principle. This is how iText works:

```
// step 1: create the document
Document document = new Document();
// step 2: create a writer that
// a. listens to the document
// b. writes to an outputstream
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);
// step 3: open the document
document.open();
// step 4: add as much content you want
document.add(...);
// step 5: close the document
document.close();
```

In your code, you have this:

```
// step 1: create the document
Document document = new Document();
// step 2: create a writer that
// a. listens to the document
// b. writes to an outputstream
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);
for (some iterator) {
    // step 3: open the document
    document.open();
    // step 4: add as much content you want
    document.add(...);
    // step 5: close the document
    document.close();
}
```

As soon as the code has gone through the loop once, the document is closed and you can't add any new content anymore. You need to change your loop like this:

```
// step 1: create the document
Document document = new Document();
// step 2: create a writer that
// a. listens to the document
// b. writes to an outputstream
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);
// step 3: open the document
document.open();
// step 4: add as much content you want
for (some iterator) {
    document.add(...);
}
// step 5: close the document
document.close();
```

Now you can still add as much content as you want, but you are closing the document only once.

**Update:** I tried formatting your code in your place, but it was hard to do because there were some unbalanced `{` and `}` instances. In your code snippet, I also don't see you opening the document anywhere. I am sure this happens *outside* the `buildPdfDocument` method. Maybe the `document` object is also closed outside this method. If so, you can remove the `document.close()` inside your method. All in all, I would advise you to write cleaner code. I see plenty of things I don't like. If you were my employee, I'd ask you to write cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you initialize the the Document Object, but do that inside your method, so every time you enter your method, a new instance of the document will be generated, and you can overwrite the old pdf version of the document - becuase this is what you are trying to achieve, I guess. It seems that a once created instance of Document cannot be reopened again.

```
public class FormularCreator {

private static Document document;


public static void createFormular() throws IOException, DocumentException {

    document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 70, 50, 50, 50);
```

and the rest of your code..